# My exports function isn't working because of error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')"

Tags: node.js, function, express, routes, module.exports

I'm new to the server side of programming and I can't figure out why the terminal is telling me that the send function in express isn't defined. I've tried putting express in the document, and I've tried different formats for the function, but I still can't figure it out. (It's complaining about the "getgameData" function)

I changed the send function thinking that it might be that you can't use the send function, but it turns out that no functions work there, but when I just try and return any other data structure, the terminal is still upset. Then, I tried restructuring the function and it still didn't work.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    var gameData = require('../models/gameData.js');

    var player = "ed";

    exports.updateGame = function(res,req){
    gameData.gameData = req.data;
    }

    exports.resetGame = function(){
    res.send(gameData.gameData);
    }

    exports.getGameData = function(res,req){
    gameData.gameData.playerNames.me = player;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/plain');
    res.send(gameData.gameData.playerNames.me);
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
** The app that connects the client side and the server side
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//all required js for Part 2
var game = require('./controllers/gameController');
var setup = require('./controllers/setupController');
var topTen = require('./controllers/topTenController');

```
// all routes

// game data routes
app.route('/api/gameData')
.get(game.getGameData())
.patch(game.updateGame)
```

Comment: pass the function, not the result of the function to .get() ? `app.route('/api/gameData').get(game.getGameData).patch...`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the callback function into the `get()`, not the function,  executed. Get will pass in `req`, `res`, `next` to your callback and then execute it.

```js
// all routes

// game data routes
app.route('/api/gameData')
.get(game.getGameData)
.patch(game.updateGame)
```

I also just noticed that you have your middleware functions arguments in the wrong order. The order is: `req, res, next`. Reference [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD).

Comment: So I have to pass the function I made into a callback function? Also I'm a student at Marist and I saw that you work for google specifically on the cloud. Do you think it's worth going into cloud computing or cyber security?

Comment: Simply pass in your function, don’t include the parentheses `()`. I don’t work for Google, though we use there cloud service. To answer your question get into whichever interests you more. They are both great fields. In addition if you don’t like it then switch, the knowledge will transfer over either way.